# Separate domains vs. one domain with alias-domains

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, permissions, fastcgi

I have set up a LAMP-server using ISPConfig 3 for the administration. PHP is running over Fast-CGI.

I have several domains, like my_site.com, my_site.net and my_site.org, but they all point to the same application/website. Each domain has its own web-root-folder and is running under its own user. The application itself is in a common directory which is owned by another user, like so:

```
# path to my_application (owned by web1)
/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/my_application/

# sym-link to my_application from my_site.com-web-root (owned by web5) 
/var/www/my_site.com/web -> /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/ 

# sym-link to my_application from my_site.net (owned by web4) 
/var/www/my_site.net/web -> /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/
```

With a setup like this I have encountered a few problems concerning the permissions when performing filesystem-operations with PHP. For instance, if the application is called via my_site.com, the user `web5` is trying to write something to the application-folder. But the application-folder is owned by the user `web1`, so `web5` is not allowed to write there.

As far as I unterstand, this is how Fast-CGI works.

After some research and asking a few people, the solution seems to be to break it all down to one domain (e.g. my_site.com) and define the other domains (my_site.org, my_site.net) as alias for this one domain. That way, there would be only one user who has all necessary permissions.

However, this would mean that we'd have to buy a multidomain SSL-certificate - but we already have an SSL-certificate for each domain. We were able to use them with our previous provider (managed hosting), and there we also had only one web-directory and multiple domains.

So if this was possible, I wonder: Is putting all the domains together into one v-host with one main- and several alias-domains the right approach in this case? Or may I have misunderstood something?

Comment: what about using .htaccess to redirect all other domains to the domain/directory where you host the application?

Comment: @Hex I guess this is not an option since it is important that the top-level-domain stays like how the user entered it. It's also needed within the application. And as far I understand, the user would still not be allowed to perform filesystem operations.

Comment: Ok then try creating a group, add the users to that group and then give the necessary permissions to the directory for that group.

Comment: @Hex They already are in the same group (`client1`) and I've already sort of "patched" the problem for the necessary directories with `chown -R g+rwx dir/`, but I'm not sure if this is really the solution since those permissions did not work in every case and they also are different from what we had before with our old hosting provider (and it worked fine with those permissions). I'm not too familiar with this and I'm afraid I migh tear a security hole in my application without noticing it... Or is it ok to have permissive group settings?

Comment: You should really go close or delete your old questions before one of them gets closed for you.

Comment: @BrentPabst I have asked only one question on SF so far and I'm referncing it in this one... But ok, I've voted for deleting it.

Comment: @Quasdunk Yes, the FAQ talks about not cross posting or double posting questions.  If you aren't getting the feedback you're looking for consider offering a bounty to attract more attention to the question.

Comment: I would aim for *one* Apache process running as *one* system user but serving *several* IP addresses corresponding to *several* domain names, each with its own SSL certificate. Use IP-based virtual hosts in the apache config. Don't know whether your management tools can handle this, though.

Comment: @MvG That sounds *very* interesting, hadn't even thought of that. Yes, getting several IP-addresses would be absolutely no problem. But does Apache then automatically spawn just one process and one user? I just hope ISPConfig will let me configure it this way... I will definitely check that out!

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

I would aim for *one* Apache process running as *one* system user but serving *several* IP addresses corresponding to *several* domain names, each with its own SSL certificate. Unless explicitely configured otherwise (e.g. using [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/suexec.html) or the `-user` option to [`FastCgiServer`](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/25#FastCgiServer)), Apache will launch all child processes as the same user it's using for its own access to the data, independently from the [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) a request belongs to. How many processes there will be depends on the server configuration, ist [MPM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mpm.html) in particular, but as long as all processes belong to the same user, you shouldn't have to care for this issue here. Use IP-based [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) in the apache config, as [name-based](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html) SSL certificate selection requires [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which still isn't supported by all clients.

I don't know whether your management tools can handle this. Feel free to edit this answer and provide details on that once you know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, and thanks again for your answer. Unfortunatelly this did not quite work out, so I've decided to go for a multi-domain SSL-cetificate. +1 for your effort though!